# What to name a variable which you want to name after its type?

Tags: c++, variables, types

Let's say I have an `enum class breed` and I want to initialize a variable of type `breed` and I want to name the variable "breed"

```
struct dog{
    enum class breed{
        shepherd, husky, terrier
    };
    breed breed; // I don't know what to name this.
};
```

`dog::breed` makes sense, but `dog.breed` also makes sense. I don't know what to name these so they don't clash.

Comment: Recall that C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: Use your imagination, and make them different.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Tell that to the standard library.

Comment: This question should be reopened. An answer could describe various naming conventions to avoid name clashing. Then everyone can pick their favorite one.

Comment: There is a common argument to variable naming that you do not put the type into the variable name.  If the variable changes type, i.e. `int` to `double`, you will need to rename the variable in all of the modules.  This doesn't seem to happen much, which means you can't trust the technique.  See also Hungarian Notation.

Comment: One common technique is to append "_t" to types, to denote that the identifier refers to a type rather than a variable.  Some people prefix the letter "C" to indicate the identifier is a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

A common practice that (I guess) swapped over from Java is to start the class / enum name with a capital letter:

```
Breed breed
```

Comment: This method is frowned upon in most coding styles, due to errors injected by typos and the readability is diminished.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: You mean the Capital letter or using the same name? I know it is difficult in the format of a SO comment, but could you elaborate a bit. I'm e.g. not sure how a typo could inject an error as I can think of very few situations where you can use either a type or a variable name without the compiler complaining and even then (e.g. sizeof) it doesn't make a difference. While the `_t` - suffix technique is also very common (and I personally prefer it) those names are IIRC reserved for POSIX names.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I just read your comment under the question and I want to point out tha scheme proposed by me is not the same as hungarian notation. I'm not encoding the type name here but recognize that the name is suitable for the type as well as for the variable, which is mainly because it has a very specific purpose (contrary to e.g. `int`, `double`, `std::map` etc).